# How to create an executable for a shell script in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, executable

I have written a simple Shell script named decBright.sh that decreases my screen brightness by a bit every time I run it. However, I do not want to open the terminal and execute `bash decBright.sh` every single time.

Instead, I want to create some kind of executable file that I can place on my Desktop, which will run my script when it is double-clicked. One answer I found [here on the askUbuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329315/how-can-i-create-an-executable-in-linux-beginner) did not work for me.

Is there some other way to do it?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Comment: also you may be interested bind to the script a hotkey, e.g. with every press will decrease the brightness... [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination)

Comment: Why did the suggested mechanism from the Ubuntu forums not work? What desktop are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An executable in linux is a file with the executable bit on. Thus you simply modify it with `chmod`:

```
chmod +x decBright.sh
```

Then you can run it with:

```
./decbright.sh
```

You can also run it by double-clicking in many graphical linux distributions.

You also better provide a "Shebang": the first line of your script should specify the "interpreter":

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or any other interpreter (**at the first line of your file**).

Comment: I gave the execute permissions using chmod and also provided the shebang on the first line as you said. Yet, when I double click it, it opens up with gedit :/

Comment: Please avoid the bad habit of double-clicking (i.e. only using the mouse and the GUI)! The best way to run any script or any executable is thru a command line in a terminal. And the behavior with double-clicking is probably window manager specific.

Comment: @AkshayDamle: can you write the output of `ls -l` on your question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: True, as a programmer,always use the terminal. But from a user's perspective...